# Trim/cut video file in android

Tags: android, android-layout, video-editing

I want to extract some portion of video when user is playing that video via my application. While playing a video user can give start and end duration to cut the video. so are there any way to cut the video based on duration and save to sd card ?

Comment: you can use the camera recorder to record the stream

Comment: @vipin: Can you please provide more info on that

Comment: have ever worked with surface view .........

Comment: Do you want to cut a prerecorded video? I really don't understand what are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to cut prerecorded video

Comment: @SebastianAnnies I am using your MP4 library and using ShortenExample . But it's giving me outofmemory error :(

Comment: This is not the correct place to discuss that. Please write to the mp4parser discussion [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mp4parser-discussion). (Hint try to open the IsoFile with a FileChannel object since with them I can do memorymapping tricks)

Comment: This lib is perfect to cut videos 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205299/android-sdk-cut-trim-video-file/11551682#11551682

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42897025/3753273)  for cutting videos using ffmpeg in android

Answer (score 0):

You may try to compile and integrate ffmpeg into your project. I used ffmpeg to cut video and audio, is very fast, no recording needed. I've NO experience on doing it on android, but It should work. Here you have the official wiki page about ffmpeg on android:

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be done using [MP4Parser](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) its purely written in java and can be used with android and also [here](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/ShortenExample.java) is an example of doing video shorten in java By [Sebastian-annies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829133/sebastian-annies)

Comment: Heyy Vivek can you please change the second [link](https://mp4parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/ShortenExample.java) to [this](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/ShortenExample.java) because it has been chaged

Answer (score 0):

Android uses Mp4Parser/isoParser for Trimming Videos here is the example to trim the video https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-4.4.2_r2/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/TrimVideo.java and as mentioned he usees isoParser which u can get it from "git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mp4parser"

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Android-video_trimmer](https://github.com/a914-gowtham/Android-video-trimmer) library.it supports Android 10 as well

Answer (score -7):

@Ravi --- video can be played in videoview or surfaceview android inbuilt class. In surfaceview you can start a thread to record you video from the position you select to position you want using MediaRecorder

```
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/recordvideooutput.3gpp");
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
    recorder.prepare();
```

YOUR mholder is the SurfaceHolder holder for attaching surface view

calling these two method will start and stop recording and the file will be written to /sdcard/recordvideooutput.3gpp

```
recorder.start();
recorder.stop();
```

use the developer guide http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: This answer is not answering the question at all.