# mediaRecorder to record last X seconds

Tags: android, video-capture, duration, android-mediarecorder

I've succeeded recording video using the `mediaRecorder` class on Android.

However, what I need to do now is to make it record till I tell it to stop, but keep only max of X seconds recorded.

For example, if I've started recording at time=0 (seconds), and I've set it to record max of 10 seconds, if I stop the recording on time=20 (seconds), the recorded video will be of the 10..20 seconds period.

The only thing similar to what I've found is [setMaxDuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxDuration%28int%29), but that automatically stops after the specified time was set, so in my case it will record only the first 10 seconds.

Comment: @Tushar No. Sorry. It was a long time ago.

Comment: @Tushar I do not yet know if this is a working example, as I'm just starting to investigate it, but it sounds extremely promising when I ran a test on my phone from source. Check out ContinuousCaptureActivity from grafika, which uses a CircularEncoder for the video. I imagine you can rig up another circular encoder for audio stream as well. [grafika github](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)

Comment: @jschlepp Thanks for the link. I'll check it out. :)

Comment: The app "snipback" from "hipoint" seems to do this. I don't know how they do this.

Answer (score 3):

**FOR MEDIA RECORDER TO RECORD X SECOND U HAVE TO SIMPLY PUT THIS CODE IN YOR VIDEO RECORD CODE**

```
Intent captureVideoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
captureVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
captureVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(captureVideoIntent, VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

Comment: You don't understand: I need to do it within the application, plus I need it to constantly record, and when I tell it to stop, I should give me only the last X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to accomplish what you need using just the SDKs. You could have it record a video and then when you determine it cut the video down to the last 10 seconds.

I haven't used it, but this guy suggests his library in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551682/1076683)

Comment: the mp4parser library seems promising . i could use a 2 buffer files solution , and when i'm ready for stopping the recording , merge both files and then crop the merged file . are you sure there isn't another workaround for this ? maybe set the recording's outputStream to a buffer that i will be responsible to cut where needed?

Answer (score 0):

The correct keyword for searching it is "circular buffer". 
You will see a couple of methods, which aren't trivial.
Some use NDK solutions.

My idea it is:
You know X seconds do you want to record.
Than record to fileX_1, after that it ends the recording.
Automatically start and record  fileX_2 until ends.
When it ends then record to fileX_3 AND delete fileX_2 to save space.

So the maximum storage and video length can be X * 2. The minimum can be X.

To use the circular recording I think it has to decode it to frames, store it, encode it , a lot of processing power is used, which result is batter drain and heating the device!

Comment: Isn't there a better way ? Do security cameras work in the same way?