# Start the trim video activity with an intent

Tags: android

I can take a video with an intent now what are the details to create an intent to start the default video trimmer activity? And check if it present on the device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution relies on a version of the AOSP Gallery2 package being installed on the device. You can do it like this:

```java
// The Intent action is not yet published as a constant in the Intent class
// This one is served by the com.android.gallery3d.app.TrimVideo activity
// which relies on having the Gallery2 app or a compatible derivative installed
Intent trimVideoIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.TRIM");

// The key for the extra has been discovered from com.android.gallery3d.app.PhotoPage.KEY_MEDIA_ITEM_PATH
trimVideoIntent.putExtra("media-item-path", getFilePathFromVideoURI(this, videoUri));
trimVideoIntent.setData(videoUri);

// Check if the device can handle the Intent
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(trimVideoIntent, 0);
if (null != list && list.size() > 0) {
    startActivity(trimVideoIntent); // Fires TrimVideo activity into being active
}
```

The method `getFilePathFromVideURI` is based on the answer of this question: [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

```
public String getFilePathFromVideoURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

`videoUri` is an `Uri` pointing to something like this: `content://media/external/video/media/43`. You can gather one by issuing an ACTION_PICK Intent:

```
Intent pickVideoUriIntent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickVideoUriIntent, PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

In `onActivityResult` get the uri like so:

```
....
case PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST:
    Uri videoUri = data.getData();
     ...
```

This solution works on my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3 Jelly Bean.

I am not sure if this is available on all Android devices.
A more reliable solution may be to fork the Gallery2 app and put the TrimVideo activity together with its dependencies into a library that can be delivered with your app. 
Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Only wish it would return back to my app after cropping and saving

Comment: hello sir ,
  when i follow your code i got Toast Message "Editing is not support for this image". i am not able to understand what is this please help me.
thank you.

Comment: @PratikSanyaja The first sentence of this answer explains that this answer requires you have a version of AOSP Gallery2 installed on the device. If you do not, you will get the message you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this may it helps

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 30000);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY", 0);
startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequests.REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

This code works well on API >=2.2, but the duration limit does not work on API 2.1

Comment: I dont want to take a video I said I can do that already, I want to trim a video that exists already