# Video trimming using "com.android.camera.action.TRIM" (Gallery2 package)

Tags: android, video, android-gallery

I need to implement trimming operation over a Video.I am  using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21752769/2562861) code, its works perfectly on Gallery2 package installed phones. but  its does not return `onActivityResult`(the intent will not return any results if the triiming was successful).

code:

```
Intent trimVideoIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.TRIM");

            // The key for the extra has been discovered from com.android.gallery3d.app.PhotoPage.KEY_MEDIA_ITEM_PATH
            trimVideoIntent.putExtra("media-item-path", FilePath);
            trimVideoIntent.setData(videoUri);

            // Check if the device can handle the Intent
            List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(trimVideoIntent, 0);
            if (null != list && list.size() > 0) {
                startActivityForResult(trimVideoIntent,2); // Fires TrimVideo activity into being active
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video trimming not supported", 1).show();
            }
```

Is there any way to close gallery2 after trimming and return result ?

Comment: What is file path and video uri here?

Comment: did you find any solution I need it