# how can I trim a video

Tags: java, android, video

I am trying to develop an app  which the user chooses a video and displays it  , and several operations can be performed, the first one is to trim the video Where you can choose a starting point and an ending point, and the output is a video between them
 how can I trim the video
I feel completely lost in this question

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675480/start-the-trim-video-activity-with-an-intent/21752769#21752769 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205299/android-sdk-cut-trim-video-file

Comment: Yes thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this git link to trim video in android studio

[Video Trimmer](https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer)

Follow these steps

implement gradle

```
implementation 'life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0'
```

Add View in layout

```
<life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.K4LVideoTrimmer
android:id="@+id/timeLine"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Set the K4LVideoTrimmer selected video Uri.

```
K4LVideoTrimmer videoTrimmer = ((K4LVideoTrimmer) findViewById(R.id.timeLine));
if (videoTrimmer != null) {
    videoTrimmer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
}
```

Implements OnTrimVideoListener methods

```
   @Override
public void getResult(final Uri uri) {
    // handle K4LVideoTrimmer result.
}

@Override
public void cancelAction() {
    // handle K4LVideoTrimmer cancel action
}
```