# Cut Video from the specific Time in android

Tags: android

Actually i want to cut the video from the specific time.
This is my below code:

```
String args[] = new String[] {
                "ffmpeg",
                "-y",
                "-ss",
                "[start]"+start,// set start time in second
                "-t",
                "[duration]"+duration,// set duration in second
                "-i",
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()//Curent Video path
                        + SquareVideoPath1,

                "-filter_complex",
                "scale=item", // set widthxwidth, option
                                    // 320x320,440x440,640x640(For
                                    // Instagram),720x720, 1020x120

                "-strict",
                "experimental",

                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()//Video Output path
                        + "/tomp3/water2.mp4" +outputFilePath };

        clsffmpeg.ffmpeg(args);
```

But the problem is how can i put start time and and time in this.

Comment: I have updated my answer check if that works.

Comment: Check out- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205299/android-sdk-cut-trim-video-file/42897025#42897025

Answer (score -1):

I think this [video trimmer code](https://github.com/uday-rayala/video-trimmer) can solve your problem

**EDIT**

Take a look at he [video-trimmer.c](https://github.com/uday-rayala/video-trimmer/blob/master/jni/video-trimmer.c) inside function `Java_net_video_trimmer_natives_VideoTrimmer_trim()` you will find it useful (shows the ffmpeg params).

**UPDATE**

```
String args[] = new String[] { "ffmpeg"
    , "-i"
    , inputFilePath
    , "-ss"
    , startTime
    , "-t"
    , duration
    , "-vcodec"
    ,"copy"
    , "-acodec"
    , "copy"
    , outputFilePath };
```

Replace `inputFilePath` , `startTime` , `duration` , `outputFilePath` with proper values.

Comment: But now i want to give size to my video and i m selecting size from the spinner list. And when i select size from spinner then it does not apply on the video and video is not cutting if i give size to it.

Comment: So how can i give size as per my choice to video.

Comment: @JigneshPatel I don't get meaning of "size to my video" , did you mean video aspect ratio or video duration ?