# What's the better way to optimise video file size in android programmatically?

Tags: android, file, video, optimization, video-processing

I want to reduce the size of a video file to less than 25mb. Is there a way to achieve it without using any third party library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with my [mp4parser](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mp4parser/) library. Have a look at the `ShortenExample` it does exactly what the name suggests. Since the library cannot re-encode the video it can only cut the video at I-frames. So the points in time where you can make a cut are quite coarse.

On Android 4.1 you can access the hardware codecs via MediaCodec API which could be an option (but I haven't seen any example of that yet)

Or, you can use this class: [TrimVideoUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-4.2.1_r1.2/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/TrimVideoUtils.java)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551682/1796309