# Android cut long video and get videos pieces separately

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, video-editing

I would like to 2 to 3 minutes long clip from a long video. So far I only managed to play the long video using a `videoView`.

```
// Set the media controller buttons
if(mediaController ==null){
    mediaController = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this);

    // Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController.
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);

    // Set MediaController for VideoView
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
}

try {
    // ID of video file.
    int id = this.getRawResIdByName("kung_fu_panda_3");
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + id));

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mVideoView.requestFocus();

// When the video file ready for playback.
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        mVideoView.seekTo(position);
        if (position == 0) {
            mVideoView.start();
        }

        // When video Screen change size.
        mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                // Re-Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController
                mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like you are including the video with your app rather than streaming it from a server? Do you mean you just want some way to cut just a small part of a video to include with your app, or do you want to whole video included and the ability to seek to a particular position in the video?

Comment: @Mick yes I have the video in the sdcard, and I want to cut small part of the video and play it alone, not seek to a particular position

Comment: Your code above should work to play only the section of the video you want - you just need to change the position == 0 to whatever seek time you want in milliseconds. Are you seeing some problem when you do this?

Comment: @Mick no problem with that, but the seekbar will show the time for the long video, isn't better to use mediaPlayer with surfaceView? or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205299/android-sdk-cut-trim-video-file/42897025#42897025